# How can I improve the response time on my query when using ibatis/spring/mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring, ibatis

I have a database with 2 tables, I must run a simple query `

```
    select * 
    from tableA,tableB 
    where tableA.user = tableB.user 
    and tablea.email LIKE "%USER_INPUT%"
```

Where user_input is a part of the string of tablea.email that has to match.

The problem:

The table will carry about 10 million registers and its taking a while, the cache of ibatis (as far as I know) will be used only if the previous query looks the same. example: for USER_INPUT = john_doe if the second query is john_doe again the cache willt work, but if is john_do will not work(that is, as I said, as far as I know).

current, the tableA structure is like this:

```
id int(11) not_null auto_increment
email varchar(255)not_null
many more fields...
```

I dont know if email , a varchar of 255 might be too long and could take longer time because of that, if I decrease it to 150 characters for example, would the response time will be shorter?

Right now the query is taking too long... I know I could upgrade to more memory to the servers but I would like to know if there is other way to improve this code.

tableA and tableB have about 30 fields each and they are related by the ID on a relational schema.

Im going to create an index for tableA.email.

Ideas?

Comment: The indexes will help, but `LIKE '%anything%'` is pretty much the problem, and I can't think of anything to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cannot utilize indexes on LIKE queries where the wildcard precedes the search string (`%query`).

You can try a Full-Text search instead. You'll have to add a FULLTEXT index to your email column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablea
ADD FULLTEXT(email);
```

From there you can revise your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA,tableB 
WHERE tableA.user = tableB.user 
AND MATCH (tablea.email) AGAINST ('+USER_INPUT' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You'll have to make sure you can use full text indexes.

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Hello, how does the FULLTEXT index affects the performance on my DB for the other methods that make a request? isnt it going to take too much memory?

Comment: by the way, I am using mysql 5.6, so, no fulltext index is available (since it is an InnoDB)

Comment: The index is going to require more memory. It shouldn't significantly impact the performance of your other queries so long as you have enough memory. All indexes require additional memory.

Comment: @jpganz18 If you're on 5.6 you can use full text indexes with InnoDB. 5.5 and lower you cannot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 5.1 , only from 5.6 of greater is available

Comment: by the way, I just realized are not 400k , are 10 million registers

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running an execution plan for that query in your DB. That'll tell how the DB plans to execute your query, and what you're looking for is something like a "full table scan". I'd guess you'll see just that, due to the `like` clause, and an index the email field won't help that part.

If you need to search by substrings of email addresses you might want to consider the granularity of how you store your data. For example, instead of storing email addresses in a single field as usual you could split them into two fields (or maybe more), where everything before the '@' is in one field and the domain name is in another. Then you could search by either component without needing a `like` and then indexes would significantly speed things up significantly. For example, you could do this to search:

```
WHERE tableA.email_username = 'USER_INPUT' OR tableA.email_domain = 'USER_INPUT'
```

Of course you then have to concatenate the two fields to recreate the email address, but I think iBatis will let you add a method to your data object to do that in a single place instead of all over your app (been a while since I used iBatis, though, so I could be wrong).